# Azure sql database backup and exporting data-tier application

Tags: backup, azure-sql-database, encryption, azure, always-encrypted

Currently i have an azure subscription in it has a server and a database.

How could i setup azure SQL database backups that will run automatically for example every 15 mins? is there a way? if yes how do i recover this kind of backups? and how much it will cost?

as my interim when i am backing up i just export data-tier application and now that i implement an encrypted column (i used always encrypted method) i cant export it, i am encountering an error saying that

> Could not export schema and data from database. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> One or more errors occurred. (mscorlib)
>
> ---
>
> One or more errors occurred.
>
> ---
>
> One or more errors occurred.
>
> ---
>
> One or more errors occurred.
>
> ---
>
> One or more errors occurred.
>
> ---
>
> Explicit conversion from data type varchar(max) encrypted with
>   (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name =
>   'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = '*****',
>   column_encryption_key_database_name = '******') collation_name =
>   'Latin1_General_BIN2' to nvarchar(max) encrypted with (encryption_type
>   = 'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = '****',
>   column_encryption_key_database_name = '*******') is not allowed.
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 529)

I am a newbie when it comes to azure and as a DBA i hope you could help me guys.

Comment: BACPAC (exports) are not a suitable backup\DR solution. Azure SQL Database has automatic backups in place. Check out [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automated-backups) in Docs.

Comment: now i understand thank you so much for this one. but regarding to my second question.is there anyway that i can still export data-tier even if a column in the database is encrypted?